# How to get text of innerHTML element?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, attributes, getattribute

ProductNames is an array of required data when using this line:

```
ProductNames[3].find_element_by_css_selector('.aok-align-bottom').get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

I'm getting this:

```
<span class="a-icon-alt">4.3 out of 5 stars</span>
```

So how can I extract only exactly text **4.3 out of 5 stars** from span tag

Comment: `.getText()` should work.

Comment: Wouldn't that be solved by using innerText instead of innerHTML?

Answer (score 0):

You should include in your css_selector this `>span` too, and search get_attribute("innetHTML") on `<span class="a-icon-alt">4.3 out of 5 stars</span>`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
ProductNames[3].find_element_by_css_selector('.aok-align-bottom').get_attribute("innerHTML").text
```

Comment: this one tried but after using get_attribute it becomes string so,string has no attribute text

Answer (score 0):

You don't extract from `innerHTML`. Rather you extract *text* or the value of any *attribute* of a [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139).

To extract the text `_4.3 out of 5 stars_` you need to move one step deeper to the `<span>` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
ProductNames[3].find_element_by_css_selector('.aok-align-bottom>span.a-icon-alt').get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

Or simply:

```
ProductNames[3].find_element_by_css_selector('.aok-align-bottom>span').get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

As an alternative, you can also use the *text* attribute as follows:

```
ProductNames[3].find_element_by_css_selector('.aok-align-bottom>span.a-icon-alt').text
```

Or simply:

```
ProductNames[3].find_element_by_css_selector('.aok-align-bottom>span').text
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)